# Copy the shortcut/hotkey to another project

Tags: unity

I modified my unity shortcut and later i found out that the new shortcut is not available in my new project i created.  it's only available in my previous project (where i created the shortcut). So how to copy this shortcut to other project ? Also i'm confused why the shortcut is project based ? not user based ?

Comment: What steps did you tale to modify your Unity shortcut?

Comment: @DMGregory i went to top menu bar  : /unity/shortcut/ and just modify some of keys there.